# Where do I find the code that generates text overlays (such as "Out of Stock") on product images on product category webpages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can't find the code that generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="woocommerce">
    <span class="soldout">Out of stock</span>
</div>
```

I've searched in all the files that came with the WooCommerce plugin for the text "soldout".

I downloaded my whole website and searched for "soldout" and could not find it.

I even searched (via a MySQL query "... like '%soldout%'") in the WooCommerce tables and other tables in my WordPress database and could not locate the text "soldout".

I would like to see where this code resides so I can hook into it to add additional custom overlays such as "Preferred".

Comment: Quick search found this: https://www.wpdecoder.com/php/woocommerce-change-out-of-stock-text/

Comment: Nope.  Thanks for the link.  I tried that and many similar.  I simply can't find the code that generated the HTML calling for class "soldout".

Answer (score 0):

I found the code.  **This is a warning to others that Windows Explorer, even though it has the feature to search in "File contents", should not be used to locate text inside files**.

I used Notepad++ to search the files in my downloaded website for "soldout".  Notepad++, unlike Windows Explorer, was able to locate not only the files that contained the text that I was looking for but also the line number where the text was located on in the file.